# Registry key not found and not getting deleted as well

Tags: vbscript, windows-installer, registry, regedit, registrykey

I have hosted MSI on a apache server.
There is a service exe which I have run on my system with SYSTEM privileges.
This service fetches the MSI from the server and then this service (written in C++) uses ShellExecute to run a batch file which has the below command:-

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32\msiexec.exe /i "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MY_MSI.msi" /qn /norestart /l*v "C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\MY.log"
```

and finally runs the MSI that was fetched from the server.
This, MSI has a CustomAction as below:-

```
<CustomAction Id="Delete" Script="vbscript" Return="ignore" Execute="immediate">
            <![CDATA[const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
                      Dim Shell: Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                      strKeyPath = "Software\Mine"
                      Function Log(msg)
                          Const msiMessageTypeInfo = &H04000000
                          Set record = Session.Installer.CreateRecord(1)
                          record.StringData(0) = "[1]"
                          record.StringData(1) = CStr(msg)
                          Session.Message msiMessageTypeInfo, record
                      End Function
                      Log("Path : ")
                      Log(strKeyPath)
                      Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & "." & "\root\default:StdRegProv")
                      DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeypath

                      Sub DeleteRegKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath)
                        If objRegistry.EnumKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys) = 0 Then
                          Log("Key exists!")
                        Else
                          Log("Key does not exists!")
                        End If
                        If IsArray(arrSubkeys) Then
                            Log("Entered If statement.")
                            For Each strSubkey In arrSubkeys
                                Log("Key : ")
                                Log(strSubkey)
                                DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strKeyPath & "\" & strSubkey
                            Next
                        End If
                        str = "HKCU\" & strKeyPath & "\"
                        Log("Deleting : ")
                        Log(str)
                        Shell.RegDelete(str)
                        Log("Deleted")
                      End Sub]]>
        </CustomAction>
```

Though the key is present. But, in the log, it is logged that the "Key does not exists!".
I am not able to find that why the key is not found though it present. Therefore, deletion of the key is also not happening.
But, when I execute this MSI from my system by double clicking it, the registry key is found (in the log, it is logged that "Key exists!" and is getting deleted as well.
My purpose is to delete it.

Comment: I compared the below 2 logs:- Log1 (generated on running the MSI manually from the system) and Log2 (generated when MSI is fetched and copied to the system and then executed). The major difference between two is that in Log1 the value of LogonUser poperty is ashish.rana which is the name of local account on my PC. And in Log2, the value of LogonUser property is SYSTEM

Comment: Yes, this means there is no ordinary `HKCU` profile to access since this is a machine and not a user account . I suppose you can try to run with a regular admin user account, but `HKCU` registry keys are considered *"user data"* and should generally be left behind - potentially with instructions on how to clean them out manually. You can only clean out the profile for the user installing (one user) via the setup by conventional means, so you might consider doing any cleanup on application launch instead of during the setup.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the msiexec.exe process is running elevated under the SYSTEM account and doesn't have access to the 'current user' registry hive.

One feasible way to accomplish this would be to create a Custom Action, with a condition of "REMOVE~=ALL", to create an Active Setup key during uninstall (the user would have to log off and log back in for Active Setup to run once).  Take particular note of the StubPath value:

```
Dim wshShell : Set wshShell = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" )
Dim productCode : productCode = Session.Property("ProductCode")
wshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\" & productCode & "\", ""
wshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\" & productCode & "\Version", "1,0,0", "REG_SZ"
wshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\" & productCode & "\ComponentID", "Cleaning Mine Registry", "REG_SZ"
wshShell.RegWrite "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Active Setup\Installed Components\" & productCode & "\StubPath", "REG DELETE HKCU\Software\Mine /f", "REG_SZ"
Set wshShell = Nothing
```